# SpringBoot con Mysql, error al conectar

Tags: mysql, spring-boot

Estoy intentando conectarme a la BBDD de mysql con SpringBoot pero me da error

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import java.sql.*;

@RestController
@RequestMapping
public class miController {

    private static String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    private static String server = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/pruebas";
    private static Connection conexion = null;

    miController(){
        conectar();
    }


    private void conectar() {
         try {
             Class.forName(driver);
             conexion = DriverManager.getConnection(server, "yo", "pass");
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println("Error: Imposible realizar la conexion a BD.");
             e.printStackTrace();
         }

    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/hola", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String hola() {
        return "Hola mundo2!!  " ;
    }

}
```

El código del error que da cuando arranca la aplicación es :

```
Thu Jun 28 17:24:42 CEST 2018 WARN: Establishing SSL connection without server's identity verification is not recommended. According to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ and 5.7.6+ requirements SSL connection must be established by default if explicit option isn't set. For compliance with existing applications not using SSL the verifyServerCertificate property is set to 'false'. You need either to explicitly disable SSL by setting useSSL=false, or set useSSL=true and provide truststore for server certificate verification.
Error: Imposible realizar la conexion a BD.
java.sql.SQLException: Unable to load authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password'.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:869)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:865)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1746)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1226)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2188)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2219)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2014)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:776)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:47)
```

Comment: Si estas usando spring porque te conectas con DriverManager?? mejor conectate con spring e inyecta la conexión

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Spring Boot por defecto utiliza hibernate para la conexión con la base de datos y ya viene integrado con el. Esto es un pequeño atisbo de lo que hace.

> [Hibernate](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernate) es una herramienta de mapeo objeto-relacional (ORM) para la
>   plataforma Java (y disponible también para .Net con el nombre de
>   NHibernate) que facilita el mapeo de atributos entre una base de datos
>   relacional tradicional y el modelo de objetos de una aplicación,
>   mediante archivos declarativos (XML) o anotaciones en los beans de las
>   entidades que permiten establecer estas relaciones.

Para configurar la conexión en tu BD solo necesitas modificar un fichero en la raíz que se llama `aplication.properties`. Se configuran estos campos:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/db_springboot?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=tucontraseña
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop
logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=debug
```

La linea `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop` se encarga de crear la estructura de tu base de datos y cada vez que se reinicia el servidor borra los datos **(No lo uses en producción!!)**

Para guardar información solo necesitas crear Entities, Repositorios e inyectarlos. [Este](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z3HnFBzn7DI) es un tutorial sobre eso. Si te conectas de esa manera lo que vas a hacer es perder la cabeza tratando rehacer la rueda.

También son necesarias estas dependencias de maven en tu `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Si todo esto te parece extraño o no lo encuentras en tu proyecto intenta crear uno nuevo desde [aquí](https://start.spring.io/). Es la manera más sencilla, más rápida y más romántica de empezar con spring boot.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu aporte, lo pondré en práctica y si tengo algún problema , volveré a crear un post.

Comment: Hola, el comentario de la linea spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto= create-drop me ayudo bastante ya que tengo la misma configuración en aplication.properties, pero el problema es que mi BD si va a estar en producción y youtube lo bloqueo la empresa, ¿De casualidad tendrás otro link para isa poder guardar información?

Comment: Hola @ReinosRic. No entiendo a qué te refieres con lo del link.

Comment: Hola, perdón ni yo mismo me entendí, resulta que no tengo acceso al link que compartes, por lo que mi duda es la siguiente ¿Tendrás otra pagina que compartas para poder guardar la información de mi base de datos y así no tener conflicto de perderlos cada vez que reinicie el servidor?.

Comment: ¿Pero cual es al que no puedes acceder?

Comment: Hola, en la respuesta que dejaste hay una parte donde dice: " Este es un tutorial sobre eso" en esa parte se encuentra el link que no puedo ingresar ya que la empresa lo tiene bloqueado.También otra duda: 
El comando "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update" se usa para actualizar la BD ¿Es correcto? y también ¿Es correcto usar este comando si mi proyecto se sube a producción?

Comment: `update` modifica la estructura de la BD de datos para agregar los cambios que tengas en tus `entitys` pero no elimina los que dejas de usar. Si tu proyecto no es muy grande y no te importa perder integridad puede usarlo, de otra manera puedes meterte en problemas por inconsistencias. Los profesionales recomiendan hacer todos los cambios a tu BD de manera manual por un Administrador de Base de datos.

Comment: @ReinosRic Solo busca por internet algún tutorial de spring boot. Te recomiendo: https://spring.io/guides/gs/spring-boot/